# How to share cookie between subdomains?

Tags: angular, express, cross-domain, subdomain, setcookie

I have an express backend that is hosted on https://logindev.example.com, and a front-end that is hosted on https://www.dev.example.com. Upon login in the frontend, the auth server sets a cookie with "example.com" set as a domain attribute. But the cookie is not saved to the browser.

I see set-cookie in the response though

```
set-cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Imlkb3Vnd2FybmVyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInByb3ZpZGVyIjoiZW1haWwiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDc3NDkwODgsImV4cCI6MjIxMjU0OTA4OH0.dFeBqr_b58WEhsLf-q8IOM6_tANhweqbCIBngLnp1Pk; Domain=example.com; Path=/
```

The front-end is Angular 10 and sending an authentication request to the auth backend by using HttpClient with credentials header set to "include".
The auth backend is setting the cookie by using the following code.

```
res.cookie('token', 'xxxxx', { domain: 'example.com' });
```

I've googled to figure out this issue but no luck yet. I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me with this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In cookies setting time just use a `.` in the first of domain name:

```js
Cookie.set('key', 'value', { domain: '.example.com' })
```

The `Cookie` comes from [`js-cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) that is an awesome library for working with cookie in browser a little more simple. this trick will share the cookies with dotted domain with base domain and all its subdomains.

In the node environment it's same is above:

```js
res.cookie('key', 'value', { domain: '.example.com' });
```